# Converting safari web extension from git repo not successful

Tags: xcode, safari, safari-web-extension, web-extension

I'm trying to convert a chrome web extension to a safari extension.
My environment is a Big Sur VM with XCode 12.5.1.

When I clone the extension's git repo (https://github.com/toobeeh/skribbltypo) and try to convert it with "xcrun safari-web-extension-converter skribbltypo" (from the parent folder), it only spits out the error "Unable to parse manifest at file:///..." (the path points correctly to the repo folder where the manifest lies within).

Web research tells that the issue either may be the folder being a zip (I unsuccessfully tried many ways of downloading the repo as zip, unpacking it, unpacking a signed crx,...) or the path not being correct (I also dragged the folder to the terminal and the file:/// path is correct), with no success.

Does this have to do something with the VM i'm running?
I can't believe I've done it wrong in so many ways.
I'd be glad if someone could try the process.
Thanks in advance.